# How can I optimize this solution? (Cutting a specific part of an array given bounds)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm given a list of numbers, and given a number N, cut out N numbers from the center of the list. So, if the list is:

```
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

And N = 3, output would be:

```
5 7 11
```

Or if the list is:

```
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17
```

And N = 4, output would then be:

```
3 5 7 11
```

My current solution is O(N^2) (or at least I think it is? Idk if that nested for loop would mean this is O(N^2)), where I iterate over the array of numbers until the amount of numbers from the start to i is == the amount of numbers from (size of array - (i + cut size)). Because a cut in the middle would mean there's the same amount of numbers on the left side of the cut as the right side.

"nums" is the array of numbers I'm finding a cut in the middle for.

```
        int rightof = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> cut = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            rightof = nums.size() - (i + cutsize);
            if (i == rightof && i != 0) {
                for (int j = i; j < (cutsize + i); j++) {
                    cut.add(nums.get(j));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

The thing that's slowing this down is adding the appropriate numbers to the "cut" array. So I'm not sure how I might optimize that step.

Comment: Here cutsize is the number of elements that should be cut in the middle, correct? For example, if the array is 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 and cut size is 4, it should return 3,5,7,11 according to your example, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 3):

The Java 8 stream api makes this fairly easy. The number of elements to skip is the size minus `n` divided by two, and limit to `n` elements.

```
List<Integer> cut = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19);
int n = 3;
int sk = (cut.size() - n) / 2;
List<Integer> al = cut.stream().skip(sk).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(al);
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn the power of [`sublist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

```
List<T> result = arr.subList((arr.size()+1)/2 - arr.size()/4, arr.size()/2 + arr.size()/4);
```

Where `arr` is your `List`

Example:

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17);
arr.subList((arr.size()+1)/2 - arr.size()/4, arr.size()/2 + arr.size()/4)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
3
5
7
11
```

If you just want to do this with simple loops:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int size = arr.size();
for(int i = (size+1)/2-size/4; i < size/2+size/4; i++) {
    list.add(arr.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Might there be an optimal solution not involving methods like that?

Comment: That doesn't work for an input like "1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19". It adds 3 5 7 11 instead of just 5 7 11

Comment: @J.Doe My bad, fixed

Comment: @J.Doe I'm a bit confused about your logic here. In your example above you state `1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17` *should* return `3, 5, 7, 11`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well enough; you're given the size of the cut as well. So, the solution needs to account for if the array is 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 and the size of the cut is 2, then the answer would be 5 7.

Comment: Any luck on that?

Comment: @J.Doe Essentially what Elliot did: `arr.subList((arr.size()-cut)/2, (arr.size()-cut)/2 + cut)`

Comment: Or replace the `for` loop with: `for(int i = (arr.size() - cut)/2; i < (arr.size() - cut)/2 + cut ; i++)`